# Laravel : Using Crinsane - LaravelShoppingcart How do I retrieve user's cart when they log in

Tags: laravel, e-commerce

Suppose I store the cart in a database using `Cart::store()`...and the user logs out - logs in again **OR** logs in using a difference device - how do I retrieve **HIS** cart.

Answer (score 0):

Use the e-mail of user when you store.

```
Cart::store(auth()->user()->email);
```

To restore:

```
Cart::restore(auth()->user()->email);
```

Take care about 'CartAlreadyStoredException'.

You can make a aux table to store more then one cart, if necessary.